# Стоит ли минифицировать PHP-код?

Tags: php

Если минификация CSS-кода и JavaScript-кода уже стала правилом хорошего тона при создании серьёзных сайтов, то что насчёт PHP-кода? Что-то я не слышал, чтобы все PHP-файлы стремились объединить в один и убрать все пробелы. Вероятно, в этом нет особого смысла?

Comment: Код PHP не путешествует по сети в виде нескольких запрашиваемых файлов и следователь не накладывает дополнительные расходы на сеть. А результатом его исполнения является единый код HTML, минифицировать который тоже мало смысла, хоть и можно.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Надо ответить на вопрос "зачем"

CSS и JS - потому что эти данные передаются по сети. Возможно, по медленной сети какого-нибудь GPRS. Или, что зачастую гораздо хуже, по нестабильной сети. Меньше данных передавать - значит быстрее загрузка на клиенте. При раздаче gzip эффект оказывается сильно меньше, но если равно при деплое статика собирается, компилируется (sass/less, например, или ещё какой препроцессор), сжимается gzip'ом (чтобы nginx не на каждый запрос пережимал статику, а раздавал уже сжатую), выберите-подходящие-этапы-для-своего-проекта - то ещё один шаг с минификацией уже ничего не стоит добавить.

PHP же - исполняется целиком на сервере, исходник никуда не передаётся по сети. Какой бонус можно хотеть получить после минификации? Может быть мысль сэкономить чуть-чуть на времени парсинга исходного текста - но зачем, если парсинг исходника можно вообще не делать для каждого запроса, а переиспользовать сразу опкод? Несколько дополнений кэширования опкода было уже давно, в уже музейном PHP 5.5 [`opcache`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.opcache.php) перенесли в основной код PHP (но дефолтно он выключен).

То есть минифицировать по аналогии с JS можно, но нет ответа на вопрос "зачем". Поэтому не используется.

Comment: кстати, в древние времена это имело бы смысл... не раз встречался с требованием "не использовать 4 пробела, использовать табы" в кодестайл-гайдах, для минимизации нагрузки... имело это реальный эффект или нет - я так и не понял, я тогда верил старшим товарищам и поговорке "нет дыма без огня". Но те времена ушли, так что да, правильный ответ "нет" :)

Comment: Отлично - одной проблемой меньше!

Answer (score 0):

Нет. Код исполняется на сервере, а не передается по сети клиенту. Да и в минификации css и js в век всеобщего gzip мало. Но имеет смысл объединения мелких файлов в 1 - что бы меньше было запросов.